# Why Invoke query does not performed valid transaction?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I have setup the `byfn` from [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html#building-your-first-network). What I am going through that is invoking by this command.

> peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}

It give me an error that iI found by `docker logs {peer0_container_id}`. I also set `CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true`

> 2020-01-06 08:08:39.972 UTC [vscc] Validate -> ERRO 0ad VSCC error: stateBasedValidator.Validate failed, err validation of endorsement policy for chaincode mycc in tx 9:0 failed: signature set did not satisfy policy
>
> 2020-01-06 08:08:39.973 UTC [committer.txvalidator] validateTx -> ERRO 0ae VSCCValidateTx for transaction txId = ea10c982be12ab3762b4199a349c1409fb22bde5230667be78b2394ccdb05d37 returned error: validation of endorsement policy for chaincode mycc in tx 9:0 failed: signature set did not satisfy policy

But for this command it working fine I mean transaction is valid.

> peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'

Is there anything to configure for invoking with the first one I mean except passing the `--peerAddresses` param?

I have also added the third organization from [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html#adding-an-org-to-a-channel). And here the invoke command also work i mean valid transaction.

> peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050  --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n mycc -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'

So, why does not the same invoke is not working for the `byfn`?

**Note** for `byfn` I have removed the all images and done it from the beginning. So here is no conflict actually.